# c# linq a user list not in a string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, linq

i have a `userList` that need to exclude from the string, the code such as below

```
string[] userList={"gerald","admin","john"} ;

List<EventItem> logall= new List<EventItem>();
List<EventItem> logfilteruser= new List<EventItem>();

logall= Records.AsQueryable().Select(e => new EventItem(e)).ToList();
```

> logall will have all the records

**how to exclude the userList ?**

follow is my code for exclude the userList.

```
    if (users != "") {
        foreach (var filter in userList) {
            logfilteruser= logall.Where(x => !x.depict.Contains(filter)).ToList();
        }
```

the depict is a string attribute in Records, and this have many records, below is one of the depict string value

```
     depict= "username:\t\tgerald\r\n\t\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\t";
     depict= "username:\t\tjason\r\n\t\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\t";
```

if the `userList` is only one `value(gerald)`,the code works.When the `userList` have more than one it is not working. the result show all the records come out, it incorrect.

how i can fix the code using `linq` or other ways ? Thank and sorry for my broken English.

here i include my  EventItem and Records for reference

```
public class EventItem {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LogName { get; set; }
    public string depict{ get; set; }

    public WinEventItem(EventRecord record) {
        Id = record.Id;
        LogName = record.LogName;
        depict= record.FormatDescription();
    }
}

 public List<EventRecord> Records { get; private set; }
 private Records = new List<EventRecord>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `depict` property is a single string, this will work:

```
logfilteruser = logall.Where(x => !userList.Any(u => x.depict.Contains(u))).ToList();
```

In theory, this should also perform slightly better than `foreach (var filter in userList)` because `Any()` will return as soon as it finds a match in the `userlist`, it does not need to enumerate the entire collection each time (even if a match has already been found).

**Edit**

Here is a sample console application showing this working.

I've created an example class instead of a full class inheriting from `EventRecord`. It returns a string for `FormatDescription` just as `EventRecord` does though.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create some test data
        List<TestEventRecord> Records = new List<TestEventRecord>();
        Records.Add(new TestEventRecord { Value = "username:\t\tgerald\r\n\t\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\t" });
        Records.Add(new TestEventRecord { Value = "username:\t\tjason\r\n\t\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\t" });

        string[] userList = { "gerald", "admin", "john" };

        List<EventItem> logall = new List<EventItem>();
        List<EventItem> logfilteruser = new List<EventItem>();

        // Contains all entries
        logall = Records.AsQueryable().Select(e => new EventItem(e)).ToList();

        // Contains only 1 entry as the list is filtered
        logfilteruser = logall.Where(x => !userList.Any(u => x.depict.Contains(u))).ToList();
    }
}

public class EventItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LogName { get; set; }
    public string depict { get; set; }

    public EventItem(TestEventRecord record)
    {
        Id = record.Id;
        LogName = record.LogName;
        depict = record.FormatDescription();
    }
}

// Example class for testing
public class TestEventRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LogName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string FormatDescription()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for let me know that other ways of using foreach, but i tried this few minutes. it looks like not working, it return the max records result to me. I also try use contains first than use expect or removeall

Comment: Could you post your `EventItem` model please? You state that `depict`  is a string, but might have many records. What do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry for that, i just post my EventItem model

Comment: Oops, just got a error on it. CS1929  C# 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>#IQueryable<string>, string#' requires a receiver of type ''

Comment: I have added an example application. Could you tell me how this working code iffers from yours? Can you confirm (using the debugger) that the value for 'depict' for items in `logall` always looks something like `username:\t\tgerald\r\n\t\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\t`?

Comment: confirm for the depict is always looks something like that. original is much longer than i post in here. `"securitycode:\t\t883018\r\n\tusername:\t\tgeralim\r\n\tloginidentify:\t\t0x18ECC03\r\n\tloginGUID:\t\t{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\r\n\r\nother accounts:\r\n\tname:\t\tgeralim\r\n\tlogin GUID:\t\t{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}\r\n\r\n"`

Comment: Could you debug through your code, and the sample app in the answer, and see what's differant? The code above works for me, when `depict` is a string that looks like the above.

Comment: your code is work, but i change to my work code, not working. maybe because my work code too complexity, hard to post all the reference code in here, Thanks! tomorrow morning i'll try again

Answer (score 0):

You're refiltering the original list every time around your loop. Try the following:

```
logfilteruser = logall;

foreach (var filter in userList)
{
    logfilteruser = logfilteruser.Where(x => !x.depict.Contains(filter)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I would add the `ToList` just once, _after_ the loop. In some cases (e.g. when `logall` is an `IQueryable`) this will be more efficient.

Comment: i tried but also not working, this code always return the all records to me. Isn't the problem of every records have a depict, and my records have more than hundred ?